# vue with parcel does not render correctly

Tags: vue.js, parcel

The simple process below does not work, though I do not understand why ...
using :
npm
vue
parcel

```
mkdir samat
cd samat
npm init -y
npm install vue --save
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "samat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.12"
  }
}
```

Then I create `index.html` and `index.js`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  })
```

Finally, I run `parcel index.html`, and then look at `localhost:1234` but see only this in the browser:

```
{{message}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use in-DOM templates (i.e., the `<div id="app>{{ message }}</div>`), import the full build of Vue that includes the runtime template compiler:

```js
// import Vue from 'vue'
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm.browser' // full build
```

Comment: Can you link to a reproduction?